# ¿Buscar coincidencias en una cadena de texto a partir de una lista?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Quiero desarrollar una aplicación muy simple pero estoy bloqueado porque no sé cómo empezar.

La idea es:

- Tengo una lista de autores en un archivo TXT
- Introduzco una cadena de texto donde constan diversos autores separados por comas en una caja de texto
- Entonces, si algún autor de esa cadena coincide con los que hay en la lista, que se muestre en otra caja de texto separada

Ejemplo conceptual:

lista = "**Apellido1 Nombre1**, Apellido2 Nombre2, **Apellido3, Nombre3**"

cadena = Apellido5 Nombre5, **Apellido1 Nombre1**, **Apellido3 Nombre3**"

Resultado = "Apellido1 Nombre1, Apellido3 Nombre3"

Avance:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared file As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\User\Desktop\autores.txt")
    Public Shared autores As String = file.ReadToEnd

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    TextBox2.Text = autores

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Declaras una variable global que almacenará la lista de autores. En el evento Load de tu formulario podrías leer tu archivo TXT y almacenas su contenido en la variable lista de autores. Luego, deberías definir en que evento debería evaluarse la coincidencia (podrías agregar un botón y en su evento Click), para que muestres el resultado. Recuerda [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que avanzaste para seguir ayudándote en caso tengas problemas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @Davlio. he actualizado el código según tus indicaciones, aunque no sé realmente cómo continuar.

Comment: Esta bien que en tu lista este "Apellido3, Nombre3" y en la cadena "Apellido3 Nombre3". ¿Se debería considerar en tu resultado?, lo digo por la coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a mi comentario, espero que en tu lista "Apellido3, Nombre3" no debería tener la coma de separación.

Podrías considerar:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Shared _autores As String

    Private Shared Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim sr = New StreamReader("D:\autores.txt")
        _autores = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnBuscarCoincidencias_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscarCoincidencias.Click
        ' Convertir cadena de autores a una lista, donde la separación es ", "
        Dim listaAutores = _autores.Split(New String() {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        ' Obtener nueva cadena de autores
        Dim cadena = txtAutores.Text

        ' Convertir cadena a una nueva lista, donde la separación es ", "
        Dim nuevaListaAutores = cadena.Split(New String() {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        ' Cadena resultado
        Dim resultado = ""

        ' Recorrer cada lista para buscar los que son iguales
        For Each autor As String In listaAutores
            For Each nuevoAutor As String In nuevaListaAutores

                If autor = nuevoAutor Then

                    resultado = resultado & autor & ", "

                End If

            Next
        Next

        txtResultado.Text = resultado

    End Sub

End Class
```

Dónde,

- `.Split(New String() {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`: Devuelve una lista de cadenas, donde la cadena de separación es la coma y vacío (", "). Asimismo, `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` no considera elementos vacíos.

---

En caso no quieres considerar el `For Each`, podrías usar `Intersect`. Por ejemplo:

```
Dim interseccion As IEnumerable(Of String) = listaAutores.Intersect(nuevaListaAutores)
txtResultado.Text = String.Join(", ", interseccion)
```

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método String.Split (String(), StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método Enumerable.Intersect(Of TSource)(IEnumerable(Of TSource), IEnumerable(Of TSource))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.Join (String, IEnumerable(Of String))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tu código era justo la base que necesitaba, @Davlio. He cambiado el criterio de escisión de los autores y de presentación de los resultados de `", "` a saltos de línea. En cuanto a la sentencia `If`, he creído más conveniente utilizar `autor.Contains(nuevoAutor.Substring(0, nuevoAutor.Length - 3))` ya que me interesaba mucho buscar por los apellidos utilizando un estilo de referencia determinado (_Vancouver_) y esa ha resultado ser la mejor opción. ¡Gracias!